# NSLocalizedStringFromTable not working in CocoaPod dependency

Tags: cocoapods, nslocalizedstring

I've installed `REActivityViewController` as a pod. Here's the picture of the `Resources`folder in the pod:

[image]

And here's one of the lines trying to pull the strings:

```
    [_cancelButton setTitle:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"button.cancel", @"REActivityViewController", @"Cancel") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The button titles come out not-localized. In this example it shows `button.cancel`. It's also not just this button title but all the buttons in this dependancy.

---

EDIT

So in my Main Project under `Info` there's this. I can't click it to see what files those are. I have `NSLocalizedStrings` in my main project but I have yet to create a `.strings` files out of them:

[image]

---

EDIT

So I checked my `Pods-resources.sh` and found this:

```
 install_resource "REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController.bundle"
install_resource "REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController/Localizations/de.lproj"
install_resource "REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController/Localizations/en.lproj"
install_resource "REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController/Localizations/fr.lproj"
install_resource "REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController/Localizations/it.lproj"
install_resource "REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController/Localizations/ru.lproj"
install_resource "REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController/Localizations/uk.lproj"
install_resource "REActivityViewController/REActivityViewController/Localizations/zh-Hans.lproj"
```

Comment: Have you added the needed localizations to your project? Simply adding an .lproj folder doesn't make Xcode see your localizations.

Comment: @SevenBits So I've yet to really work with NSLocalized strings so I don't understand your question exactly. I've included an Edit that hopefully provides more information.... As for the `REActivityViewController` pod I just installed it by included it in my podfile but took no further steps with it.

Comment: Maybe you will find something more helpful in this answer:[xcode custom shell scripts slowing down compile time][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649298/xcode-custom-shell-scripts-slowing-down-compile-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured this out and it looks like it was somewhat isolated. I had checked the box `Run script only when installing` under Target -> Copy Pods Resources, because the script were painfully slow, so the script to install the bundle wasn't installing the bundle while debugging.

[image]