# Xcode 8.1 frameworks codesigning is slow

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

On Xcode 8.1, when i build or archive, the frameworks codesigning takes crazy big amount of time. Like i see following (see screenshot) for 5-10-20 seconds for each framework/dylib i use in my project. It is also a case for any system dylib.

[image]

I even suggest that i often get `This Action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)` because my session runs out of time, because archive time is so slow. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have the same issue especially with swift libraries

Answer (score 5):

Are you running Sierra?

If you do, have you checked for duplicated certificates and keys on your Keychain?

Also, check for duplicated references for keychain's databases in the following file: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist`

**NOTE**: This is basically a summary of the following threads:

- [Slow app compilation with new Sierra update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257968/slow-app-compilation-with-new-sierra-update)
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66418

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: The bit about `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist` was the helpful bit for me. Excellent find!!