# Running 1 of 2 custom shell script stuck for 2 minutes in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

***Running 1 of 2 custom shell scripts*** it stuck for 2 minutes while trying to build the app.

I tried to fix with the solution :[Xcode custom shell scripts are slowing down the compiling time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649298/xcode-custom-shell-scripts-are-slowing-down-the-compiling-time) , but still it slows the build process :(.

- Build Stuck for 2m here

[image]

- Build Phases
  [image]
  [image]

Further informations:

- Xcode 8.1
- Swift 3.0

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
    # Network
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'

    # UI side
    pod 'Material', git: 'https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material.git', branch: 'development'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'

    pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper', git: 'https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper.git', branch: 'develop'
    pod 'DropDown'

    # Facebook
    pod 'FacebookCore'
    pod 'FacebookLogin'
    pod 'FacebookShare'

    # Autolayout
    pod 'SnapKit'
    pod 'KeepLayout'

    # Metrics
    pod 'Google/Analytics'

    # Fabric.io
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'

end

target 'MyProjectTests' do

end

target 'MyProjectUITests' do

end
```

Answer (score 9):

Finally, I found a solution for this. At least the total build time now is **57sec.**

I found that `'Embed Pods Framework'` (Once `'Embed Pods Framework'` and `'CP Embed Pods Framework'`) builds twice. Anyway, I don't have an idea why I have both of them on build phases.

I found for this on Report Navigator.
[image: Report Navigator]

**Solution:**

1) I let only active `✓ Run script only when installing` only for`'[CP]Embed Pods Framework'` 
[image]
2) Optimization Level on Build Settings for debug was `-None`. I set to `Fast..`.
[image]

3) Tip: use **Simulator** instead of **Device** for minimal build time.

Comment: I did this and I had more issues :/

Comment: worked for me, build is now not stucked in step 3 after uncheck "Run script only when installing"

Answer (score 0):

Added this at the end of you `Podfile`

```
post_install do |installer|
    puts("Update debug pod settings to speed up build time")
    Dir.glob(File.join("Pods", "**", "Pods*{debug,Private}.xcconfig")).each do |file|
    File.open(file, 'a') { |f| f.puts "\nDEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf" }
  end
end
```

Comment: what mean of this?

Comment: add this to your `Podfile`